# Remove headings on several pages of TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

My table of contents in moving into the 3-4 page domain, and i have noticed that this causes headings and pagenumbers to appear.
This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

%Indholdsfortegnelse
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indholdsfortegnelse}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\lhead{Gruppe BA3-1-E20}
\chead{Aalborg Universitet}
    %DETTE ER BILLED TIL HEADER%
    \rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1.5cm]{Billeder/AAU lille billed.png}}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, right=20mm, left=20mm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

This way removes the headers and pagenumber on two pages, but how can remove on all pages, regardless of length of TOC?

Comment: use `\pagestyle{empty}`  not `\thispagestyle{empty}`  then set the page style you want for your main text after the cleardoublepage

Comment: I've tried this. This way wont add my original header on the rest of the pages.

Comment: As I said, use `\pagestyle{headings}` or whatever page style you want after your front matter to set up the headings for the document parts where you want headings.

Comment: Yes, doing this will add the pagenumber in the top right corner, and wont add my custom headings.

Comment: It will If you specify the page style that has your custom headings. As you have shown no example only you know the name you used so I guessed `headings`.

Comment: You are right, i needed to use \pagestyle{fancy}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `\pagestyle{empty}` not `\thispagestyle{empty}` then set the page style you want for your main text after the `\cleardoublepage` with `\pagestyle{fancy}` or whatever page style you needfor the main document.